# VS2010 Winforms Usercontrol changes not showing in parent form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I've created a series of usercontrols.  Dragged one of the controls to the main form.  It shows OK.  Went back and made a change to the design of the user control.  Rebuilt project. Cleaned project.  manually removed all project binaries including the obj folder. Change still doesn't show on the usercontrol hosted on the main form.  Dragging a new instance of the control from the tool box only shows the old version of the control.
Completely removed the controls from the toolbox and adding them again fixed the problem, but surely I don't have to do this everytime I make a change?  All user controls are in the same assembly as the main form. Tool>Options>Windows Forms Designer>Auto toolbox Populate is set to true.  Any ideas most appreciated.  Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do *not* add the control to the toolbox yourself.  This puts a copy of the assembly in a private directory.  Yes, this copy does not get updated automatically, you get the old control.

Rely on the "Auto toolbox populate" setting.  It automatically adds any controls you have in your loaded project(s) to the toolbox.  The added controls are at the top of the toolbox.

Comment: Thx.  Stopped me stuffing it up even more.

Comment: In case someone is looking for this option, just use:   Just go to Tools -> Options -> Windows Forms Designer and set AutoToolboxPopulate to true

Comment: Darn, unfortunately the user control isn't updating even though `Auto toolbox populate` was turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with answer 1 that that is what is supposed to happen, and often does. But it doesn't always work and will work partially sometimes.

For example my current Solution.

Project 1 namespace ToolsTester - This is just a temporary form to test the view tools in the 2nd project.

Project 2 namespace UltimateFileFinder - This has three views.

The first 2 views (user controls) UltFilesView and UltSlideShow appeared as usual on the toolbar so I could drag them onto ToolsTester to try them out.

Then I added another user control UltPanel, this will not go onto the toolbox. Though it compiles without errors.

I have come across this problem a few times, sometimes removing and reasserting the reference fixes it. Other times I would have to remove the test project and create a new one.

I tested Visual Studio (full version) before release and this was one of the areas I reported back, so the problem was known pre-release.

This project I am on now I know that I will need to remove the test project and create a new one, in this case the tester is only a few simple caller and event responses, that is not always the case, there are times when the tester project can be quite complex because it is mimicing the target that the tools will be part of.